# Permissive CORS - Arbitrary Origin Trust, Remedial Action?

Tags: cors

I was completing an assessment for a client and discovered that web application implemented a Permissive CORS policy which allowed for a Arbitrary Origin Trust.

Request:

```
Host: [REDACTED]
User-agent: blah
Accept: */*
Accept Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: https://arbitrary-domain.com
Connection: close
Content-Length:  16
```

Server Response:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Origin
Server: [REDACTED]
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://arbitrary-domain.com
X-Powered-By: [REDACTED]
Date: [REDACTED]
Connection Close
Content-Length: 6295

{JSON Content}
```

It was also discovered that the CORS Policy was configured using wildcards such as (*), meaning that any domain can access resources on this site. Shortly after this, I was able to exploit the issue and compromise sensitive information.

Researching fixes for this issue aren't very clear, or that I simply don't understand the remedial action suggested. I also see a lot of remedial action aimed at CSRF but not for CORS, so I am a little stuck on this. Exploiting this vulnerability appears to be a lot easier than fixing it.

My question is, what would the suggested remedial action be for this vulnerability? Is there a configuration that can be applied to IIS? What would one do to remediate this issue? As this vulnerability is pretty serious.

Any advice would be highly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: I understand there is a whitelist approach to fix this issue but the ambiguity comes in where this whitelist is configured. Is there a configuration file that needs to configured on the host?

Comment: Try to whitelist your Access-Control-Allow-Origin :https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

Comment: Thanks for your response Soufiane! I have read up quite extensively with regards to the whitelisting approach but I don't find a clear answer where the white list is configured, is there a configuration file within IIS or is there something else that needs to be configured.

Comment: I believe it's a project-specific configuration. I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7

Comment: Thank you very much Soufiane, the link did help. Plus with a little bit of research I was able to find the fix and apply it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Soufiane I was able to find the answer, links are provided below:

https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458444/enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-iis7

Here is other research I did and they also provide fixes for other server variants such as Apache, Nginx and so forth.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795268/how-to-allow-multiple-origin-domains-by-access-control-allow-origin-in-web-confi